# Must $Q^\mathsf{T}Q = I$ if $(Qx)^\mathsf{T}(Qx) = x^\mathsf{T}x$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $Q$ is a matrix (perhaps neither square nor real) that satisfies $(Qx)^\mathsf{T}(Qx) = x^\mathsf{T}x$ for all real column vectors $x$ of the right dimensions.

Must $Q^\mathsf{T}Q = I$? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $（Qx)^T(Qx)=x^Tx$ is equivalent to $x^TQ^TQx=x^Tx$ for all $x$. Thus for all $x,y$,
$$ (x+y)^T(x+y)=(x+y)^TQ^TQ(x+y)^T$$
or
$$ x^Tx+2x^Ty+y^Ty=x^TQ^TQx+2x^TQ^TQy+y^TQ^TQy$$
from which one has
$$ x^Ty=x^TQ^TQy. $$
Take $x=e_i,y=e_j$ and then
$$ (Q^TQ)_{ij}=\delta_{ij}, i,j=1,2,\cdots,n. $$
Thus $$ Q^TQ=I.$$

Answer (score 6):

Yes if $Q$ is real; if $Q$ isn't real you probably don't want to be taking the transpose.

First note that by [polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) this condition is equivalent to the condition that $\langle Qx, Qy \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$ for all vectors $x, y$, where $\langle x, y \rangle = x^T y$. This is in turn equivalent to the condition that $\langle x, Q^T Q y \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$ for all $x, y$, or

$$\langle x, (Q^T Q - I) y \rangle = 0$$

for all $x, y$. Taking $x = (Q^T Q - I) y$ gives that $\| (Q^T Q - I) y \| = 0$ for all $y$, hence $(Q^T Q - I) y = 0$ for all $y$, hence $Q^T Q = I$.

Matrices satisfying this condition are sometimes called *isometries*.